# Office add-in pinvoking SetWinEventHook

Tags: c#, winapi, ms-office, vsto, pinvoke

I need to pinvoke the SetWinEventHook function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a C# VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) add-in.

In very limited testing, it seems to work ok when I pass the WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT flag to SetWinEventHook, but since this is a VSTO add-in that supposedly runs in the same process as the Office application (ie Outlook), I'm wondering whether this is bad practice.  If OUTOFCONTEXT merely adds some additional marshalling overhead but is safe, then I can deal with a small performance hit, but if there are other issues, then would it be better to use the in process flag (WINEVENT_INCONTEXT) and if so, how to obtain the hmodWinEventProc parameter to SetWinEventHook?

Comment: You may find the [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) sample project helpful.

Comment: Great article.  Didn't know you could use WH_KEYBOARD in .NET